# Firebase function really slow

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm having a problem with a firebase function, using admin api to read then write to firestore.

See the code below:

I've commented by 2 console logs, which takes between 2-5 minutes to execute. The dataset in firestore is small (only a few records).  Any advise on what I'm clearly doing wrong please?

Thanks

(edited as requested with rest of code. This is taken direct from Stripe's github examples)

```
const processTheOrderApp = express();
processTheOrderApp.post(
  '/',
  bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }),
  (
    request: { headers: { [x: string]: any }; rawBody: any },
    response: {
      status: (
        arg0: number
      ) => { (): any; new (): any; send: { (arg0: string): any; new (): any } };
      json: (arg0: { received: boolean }) => void;
    }
  ) => {
    const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
    let event;
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    }
    // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
      const session = event.data.object;
      addPaymentDataToOrder(session); // Here we can proccess the order data after successfull payment
      // (e.g. change payment status in Firebase Database and call another function)
    }
    // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
    response.json({ received: true });
  }
);
// Exporting our http function
exports.processTheOrder = functions.https.onRequest(processTheOrderApp);


function addPaymentDataToOrder(session: any) {
  console.log('adding payment'); ////between this console log
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('orders')
    .where('paymentSessionId', '==', session.id)
    .limit(1)
    .get() // getting the order which matches the session id, should be only one so limited to one result
    .then((query: any) => {
      console.log('found item');  ////and this console log
      const thing = query.docs[0];
      var orderDoc = thing.data();
      thing.ref.update({
        checkedOut: true,
        payment: session,
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: are you using the admin SDK to access firestore? Why not use the firestore APIs directly?

Comment: yes admin in a firebase function. `const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();`.  Following their docs on using admin in firebase functions. Is this not right?  This is server-side code responding to a payment gateway webhook

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire function code, not just the query.  You could be doing something else wrong.

Comment: @DougStevenson, have done just now...

Comment: You're not correctly handling any of the promises returned by Firestore APIs.  They must all fully resolve before you send the response.

Comment: Could you show me a better way by example pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's slow because if a function in the firebase cloud functions is not called/invoked in 2 minutes, it goes into a cold start. Check out this reference.
https://medium.com/@siriwatknp/cold-start-workaround-in-firebase-cloud-functions-8e9db1426bd3

Comment: I agree with this answer. During busy periods response is faster from the functions...